# dialog window with edittext closes when edittext is clicked

Tags: android

I have a window that opens in a Dialog theme, which is how I want it to look. it's to update the title of a note (example)... so there is a text box and 2 buttons.

problem is as soon as I click on the edittext for the keyboard to show up the dialog window closes !!!!

this is the declaration I have in the mainfest for the dialog activity (note: I tried with the windowSoftInputMode value and without)

```
<activity android:name=".EditComment"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="stateAlwaysVisible"
    android:label="Comment"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

never mind guys, stupidity at it's best....

I had setOnClickListener for the edittext for some reason   doh